# CSRF Implementation and Stripe API

Tags: web, stripe-payments, csrf

Is the following a secure implementation of CSRF token verification? Specifically, I want to call this Stripe API endpoint:

`https://connect.stripe.com/express/oauth/authorize?redirect_uri=https://example.com&client_id=ca_11111&state={STATE_VALUE}`
 and the Stripe docs say

> To prevent CSRF attacks, add the state parameter, passing along a unique token as the value. We’ll include the state you gave us when we redirect the user back to your site.

I am thinking of implementing like this:
- browser generates a random token and stores it in a cookie (or local storage)
- browser calls the above endpoint
- stripe redirects to my application at `https://example.com`
- when I get the response back, I check the contents of the `state` parameter and compare it to the value stored in local storage, or in my cookie.

Is this a secure/correct implementation of CSRF? Or do I need to somehow involve a backend service?

(Stripe docs here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in the Rocket Ride example written by Stripe themselves in NodeJS, the state is just calculated on the server as a random string and added to the session of the user.  When Stripe responds at the redirect_uri they just compare the state from the user's session with the state included in the response.  The following two code snippets are taken from the following - https://github.com/stripe/stripe-connect-rocketrides/blob/master/server/routes/pilots/stripe.js

```
/**
 * GET /pilots/stripe/authorize
 *
 * Redirect to Stripe to set up payments.
 */
router.get('/authorize', pilotRequired, (req, res) => {
  // Generate a random string as `state` to protect from CSRF and include it in the session
  req.session.state = Math.random()
    .toString(36)
    .slice(2);
   // more stuff below
});
```

And for the check -

```
/**
 * GET /pilots/stripe/token
 *
 * Connect the new Stripe account to the platform account.
 */
router.get('/token', pilotRequired, async (req, res, next) => {
  // Check the `state` we got back equals the one we generated before proceeding (to protect from CSRF)
  if (req.session.state != req.query.state) {
    return res.redirect('/pilots/signup');
  }
// more stuff below
});
```